# AndroidManifest limits

Tags: android, android-manifest

My AndroidManifest.xml of one project is getting huge ( > 1000 lines ) as I have to react on certain file-types and to cover all cases is getting complex. 
I wonder if there are any limits for the manifest size. I have found nothing on this and do not want to step in a trap one day.
Is there any limit on Manifest-size / Intentfilter count, ..? Are there known bugs on certain devices for apps with a big manifest?

Answer (score 2):

It seems there are a few limitations.. But I dont think it is easy to reach them..

If you are interested I read a post a few months ago here:
[Malformed AndroidManifest.xml in Apps Can Crash Mobile Devices](http://blog.trendmicro.com/trendlabs-security-intelligence/malformed-androidmanifest-xml-in-apps-can-crash-mobile-devices/)

Regards